# Calling a Perl Module which is Installed in different path/directory

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am writing a Perl script which does -

- SSH to one of the server and do some operation using `Net::OpenSSH` Perl Module.
- I want to have entire log of the script to be stored in certain log file using `Log::Log4perl` Perl Module.
- I want to write some data to CSV file using `Text::CSV` Perl Module.

Actually these three Perl Modules have been installed in different directories.

Lets say -

- `Net::OpenSSH` is installed in /path/to/lib1
- `Log::Log4perl` is installed in /path/to/lib2
- `Text::CSV` is installed in /path/to/lib3

Since these Perl Modules has been installed in different locations, I am mentioning the respective paths in Shebang line like below:

**Method1:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -I/path/to/lib1 -I/path/to/lib2 -I/path/to/lib3

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::OpenSSH;
use Log::Log4perl;
use Text::CSV;

#continue flow of the script
..
```

This works perfectly fine for me.

I found one more method to call these Perl modules like below:

**Method 2:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use lib '/path/to/lib1';
use lib '/path/to/lib2';
use lib '/path/to/lib3';
...
```

Above method also works fine for me.

I found the standard way to call these Perl modules by the use of [FindBin](https://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html).

I am confused with its syntax. How can I achieve same using `FindBin` Perl Module.

**Method 3:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin/path/to/lib1";
use lib "$Bin/path/to/lib2";
use lib "$Bin/path/to/lib3";
...
```

This throws me following error which doesn't appears when I use first two methods (Method1, Method2).

```
unable to load Perl module IO::Pty: Can't locate IO/Pty.pm in @INC ...
```

Where I am doing wrong in Method 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$RealBin` is the directory in which the script is located. (`$Bin` is a broken version of the same thing.)

If there's no relationship between the directory in which the script is located and the directory in which a module is located, it doesn't make sense to use `$RealBin`. In fact, it usually makes more sense to use the `PERL5LIB` env var than `use lib` in such cases.

On the other hand, if the script was located in `/path/to/bin`, it might make sense to use a path relative to `$RealBin`.

```perl
use lib                 # In /path/to/bin/script,
   "$RealBin/../lib1",  #    This is /path/to/bin/../lib1, or /path/to/lib1
   "$RealBin/../lib2",  #    This is /path/to/bin/../lib2, or /path/to/lib2
   "$RealBin/../lib3";  #    This is /path/to/bin/../lib3, or /path/to/lib3
```

`$RealBin` is usually used when the script and modules are packaged together (part of the same project). Same for `use lib`, really.

Comment: In my case, there is no relation between the directory in which script is located and directory which module is located. So I was thinking to use environment var `PERL5LIB`. Could you pls provide more info on this. When I print `$ENV{'PERL5LIB'}` I didn't find anything in the terminal. Is that right way to check.

Comment: See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org). On a unixy system, `export PERL5LIB=/path/to/lib1:/path/to/lib2:/path/to/lib3`