# How to check if the Perl Module is been installed in system or not

Tags: linux, perl, perl-module

I have Perl Module (`Net::Telnet`) is been installed in location: `/home/vinod/VK_Scripts/Practices/lib`

I am executing below command to check if the module exists in system or not using below command -

```
perl -MNet::Telnet -e 'print "Installed\n"'
```

```
vinod@vinod-VirtualBox:~/VK_Scripts/Practices$ perl -MNet::Telnet -e 'print "Installed\n"'
Can't locate Net/Telnet.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Net::Telnet module) (@INC contains: /home/vinod/perl5/lib/perl5/5.30.0/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/vinod/perl5/lib/perl5/5.30.0 /home/vinod/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/vinod/perl5/lib/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

So, I have added the lib path to PERL5LIB as suggested by @ikegami in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63915586/6124824) thread.

Command was -

```
export PERL5LIB=/home/vinod/perl5/lib/perl5:/home/vinod/VK_Scripts/Practices/lib
```

And now when I check with same command whether module exists in system or not by using below command it returns true.

```
vinod@vinod-VirtualBox:~/VK_Scripts/Practices$ perl -MNet::Telnet -e 'print "Installed\n"'
Installed
```

So, question here is is there any possibility I can check whether module is exists in possible location in `perl -MNet::Telnet -e 'print "Installed\n"'` command itself rather `export` them to `PERL5LIB` before.

Comment: I like `perl -MNet::Telnet\ 99` - that's a backslash and an empty space, followed by a high version number. It will either complain or tell you the module isn't there, or it will complain that you have a version that is too low. Less typing! :)

Comment: @simbabque Its helpful info. Can we ignore `BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.` message here?

Comment: Yes. Well, if you want to use it for human consumption, absolutely. If you want to use the return value in a script, you should probably use a program that does _something_ and then ignore its output, but use the return value instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the include path (one or multiple) for the Perl interpreter on the command line itself by the **-I** parameter:

```
perl -I /home/vinod/VK_Scripts/Practices/lib -MNet::Telnet -e ''
```

You can also inspect the exit code of your script. If it is installed it will be zero, otherwise you got something than zero.

Answer (score 2):

Installation of perl module can be confirmed with following command

```
cpan -D {module}
```

output of this command looks like following `cpan -D Net::Telnet`

```
C:\...\Examples>cpan -D Net::Telnet
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.217)
CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok (v6.43)
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.81)
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Database was generated on Sat, 22 Aug 2020 09:40:39 GMT
Updating database file ... Done!
Net::Telnet
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20200314)
(no description)
        J/JR/JROGERS/Net-Telnet-3.04.tar.gz
        C:\bin\Portable\strawberry-perl\perl\vendor\lib\Net\Telnet.pm
        Installed: 3.04
        CPAN:      3.04  up to date
        Jay Rogers (JROGERS)
        jay@rgrs.com
```

Note: if module installed in none default location, as for example on web server which is not under your control (into your home directory), you have to define variable `PERL5LIB` to point installation location, to be included into `@INC` or in perl script(s) utilize `use lib ....`.

Note: perl command option `-I` allows to specify include directory to look into. If you do not mind to type long path then you can use it, although including this path into `@INC` is preferable approach. In last case you can make script executable and just type `script.pl [options] file(s)`.

Documentation: [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)